# Iterations of the radical of an integer

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, recursion

We denote for an integer $n>1$ its square-free kernel as $$\operatorname{rad}(n)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\p\text{ prime}}}p,\tag{0}$$
with the definition $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$. You can see this definition and the properties of this arithmetic function from the Wikipedia [*Radical of an integer*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) Then I wondered about a variant of two problems showed in last paragraphs of section **B 41** of Guy's book [1].

**Definition.** For each fixed integer $n\geq 1$, I consider the arithmetic function $$f(n)=f^1(n):=\operatorname{rad}(n)+1,\tag{1}$$
and we create the iterated $$f^{k+1}=f(f^{k}(n))\tag{2}$$
until $f^{T}(n)$ reaches a prime number, here thus $T=T(n)$ is a function depending on $n$ (that is the number of steps in our iteration that we need to wait until the sequence of iterated $f^{k}(n)$ reaches a prime number 
for the first time). We can call stopping time to the arithmetic function $T(n)$ (defined thus for integers $n\geq 1$ and taking positive values).

**Example 1.** Let $n=1$, then in a step the sequence of iterations reaches a prime number since $f(1)=f^1(1)=\operatorname{rad}(1)+1=1+1=2$ is a prime number. The same argument works with the composite number $n=8$, because $f(8)=f^1(8)=\operatorname{rad}(8)+1=2+1=3$ a prime number. Thus in our table $T(1)=1$ iteration, and also in this example we've seen that the corresponding  sequence defined for the integer $8$ has stopping time $T(8)=1$.

**Example 2.** We work about the calculation of $T(33)$. We iterate while the result is a composite integer. Here $\operatorname{rad}(33)=33$, thus $f(33)=34$ and since $34=2\cdot 17$ is also square-free then $f^2(33)=f(f(33))=34+1=35$. Again our last iterated, that is $35=5\cdot 7$ has no repeated prime factors, thus we write $f^3(33)=f(35)=36$. Finally $f^4(33)=\operatorname{rad}(36)+1=6+1=7$ that results a prime number. Thus we conclude that $T(33)=4$.

**Computational fact.** I did few experiments/calculations and seems that the arithmetic function $T(n)$ is erratic, thus it makes sense to study averages of consecutive values of this stopping time.

> **Question.** I would like to know if it is possible to deduce a tighter upper bound for $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{1\leq n\leq N}T(n)\tag{3}$$
>   as $N$ grows (if you are able to provide an elaborated statement about the asymptotic behaviour of $(3)$ as $N\to\infty$ feel free to do it). **Many thanks.**

**Final remarks.** My motivation was to propose a similar variant of the mentioned problems in Guy's book, now for other interesting arithmetic function $\operatorname{rad}(n)$. I've no idea about a strategy to attack the problem to get idea about the size of the average means of the $T(n)$.

### References:

[1]  Richard K. Guy, *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*, Volume I, Second Edition, Springer (1994).

Comment: Many thanks for previous upvote.

Comment: For $p$ prime do you stop immediately, so $T(3)=0?$

Comment: Yes, @RossMillikan

Comment: Since my definition was stated as I did, *no* (and now there are two answers). But now that 've seen your remark, yours is a more nice definition than mine @RossMillikan Thus I'm sorry. Now the definition is what were did the calculations and reasonings. If you want to add a different definition and calculations it also is welcome. Many thanks.

Comment: Unless I'm not mistaken, $\sum_{1\leq n\leq N}T(n)=866110654$ for $N=10^8$.

Comment: Many thanks for your example @didgogns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(n)=n+1$ if $n$ is square-free, which can happen at most three times in a row when iterating $f$, namely one of $n,n+1,n+2,n+3$ must be a multiple of $4$. And if $n$ is *not* square-free, then $2\le f(n)\le \frac n2+1$. Thus it takes up to four iterations to take $n$ to a number $\le \frac{n+3}2+1$. Thus if we start with $n\le 5+2^m$, we arrive at a number $\le 5+2^{m-1}$ after at most $4$ iterations.
Thus after at most $4\log_2(n-5)$ we are at a prime or at $4$ or $6$.
This gives the (correct, but probably very pessimistic) upper bound
$$ T(n)\le 1+4\log_2(n-5)\sim \frac 4{\ln2}\cdot \ln n\approx 5.77\ln n$$
(which then holds in similar form for the averaged $T$).

---

A more heuristic appoach is that the probability of $n$ beinf squarefree is $\frac 6{\pi^2}$, hence on average, we should be able to replace the factor $4$ above with $\frac{\pi^2}6\approx1.64$. We might also note that when $n$ is a multiple of $4$, its is a multiple of $8$ or higher about half the time etc. Thus we should then not step from $\sim 2^m$ to $\sim 2^{m-1}$, but on average more like to $2^{m-1-\frac12-\frac14-\ldots}=2^{m-2}$. Boldly combining both ideas, we get a heuristic estimate of $\sim \frac{\pi^2}6\log_4n\approx 1.19\ln n$. And there is still room for impovement by stopping t other primes than $2,3,5,7$.

Comment: Many thanks for your nice answer, it is incredible that can be stated mathematics about such Question. I am going to study it.

Comment: In my calculations before asking here I glimpsed the first sentence of your first paragraph. From your profile I see that you did study math and I add that **you've a great knack for it!**  Many thanks for your answer, I wanted ask to know what about a statement for $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{1\leq n\leq N}T(n)$, and from your answer and the other nice answer one can get a good idea about it.

Comment: @user243301: Have a look at the edit to my answer to see some added asymptotics based off of Hagen's great work.

Comment: @IskyMathews many thanks again. I am asking in this site as an amateur (adding contributions as questions), if you're interested in next future about this kind of questions, I encourage to study and exploit it since you've great skills (I've no such skills but I know how to recognize good mathematics)

Comment: Very kind @user243301, but I still have a lot to learn. I'm but a student enthusiast, as you!

Comment: $1+4\log_2(n-5)$ can be reduced to $2+3\log_2(n-5)$ because $\operatorname{rad}(n)+1$ cannot be $1 \pmod 4$.

Answer (score 2):

Based on some computations:[image: Graph up to 1000]
I would say that $ln(n)$ (the red line) appears to be a good, safe upper bound to your interesting averaged-$T(n)$ (the blue line).

I shall try to think of some ways of using bounds on $rad(n)$ or $\pi(x)$ to obtain this result, but I'm not terribly good at this sort of thing (just very, very interested!). It looks to be roughly a logarithmic growth itself.

**EDIT**: I have just messed around a bit with the logarithms, and here's what a $log_{24}(n)$ graph looks like:[image]

Could be a good lower bound beyond the intersection point (roughly $x=217$)?

Thus the current working conjecture is $log_{24}(x)<\frac{1}{x}\sum^x_{k=1} T(k)<log_e(x)$ beyond around $x=220$.

**EDIT II**: Considering the information gained from the other answer, we can derive some nice asymptotic upper bounds on the average-$T(n)$.

We see from the fact that $T(n) \leq \frac{4}{ln(2)}ln(n)$ that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1\leq k \leq n}T(n) \leq \frac{4}{n ln(2)}\sum ln(k) = \frac{4}{n ln(2)} \times ln(n!)$.

Now, [Stirling's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) tells us that $ln(n!)$ is asymptotic to $ln(\sqrt{2\pi n})+nln(\frac{n}{e}) = ln(\sqrt{2\pi n})+ln(n)-n$.

So, putting this all together, we get that the average-$T(n)$ should have the upper bound of $$\frac{4(ln(\sqrt{2\pi n})+ln(n)-n)}{n ln(2)}$$ Pretty cool!

Comment: Ah yes! Sorry, my mistake!

Comment: Many thanks for your nice answer and graphs, it is incredible that can be stated mathematics about such Question. I am going to study it.